# My code won't allow the user to quit, my answers aren't working right, neither will my .toLowerCase() and it also goes into an infinite loop

Tags: javascript, list, function, if-statement, while-loop

The function I created to check my responses:

```
function responseChecker(question) {

var valid = false;
```

The while loop I created to refuse answers I haven't specified in the code:

```
while (valid == false) {
  
var input = prompt(question)
```

This is to convert any input from the user to to lower case. It always shows an error message; when I click cancel, it says something about not being able to convert null to lowercase.

```
input = input.toLowerCase() 

try {
if(input < "a" || input > "d" && input == "q" ) 
throw "Type a letter between a and d";
if(input == '') throw 'that is empty, type something'
if(input % 1 == 0) throw 'type a letter'
alert("Thank you")
valid = true;
}


catch(err) {
alert('That is ' + err)
}


}
}
```

Quiz questions for the game in a list:

```
var quizQuestions = ["Where does Simba live? \nA) Pride Rock \nB) Kenya \nC) Great Rift Valley \nD) Desert", 
"What is the name of Simba's dad? \nA) Mable \nB) Mufasa \nC) Matata \nD) Mr Simba ", 
"Who was Simba's childhood best friend? \nA) Nala \nB) Sarabi  \nC) Shenzi \nD) Food",
"What animals are Timoni and Pumba? \nA) Rat & Cat \nB) Wild dog & mouse \nC) Warthog & Meerkat \nD) Pig & squirrel ",
"Who is Rafiki? \nA) Baboon \nB) Monkey \nC) Master Oogway 2.0 \nD) Wise Monk",
"Who killed Sima's dad? \nA) Shenzi \nB) Scar \nC) Hyena's  \nD) Takaa",
"What type of birds did were going to eat Simba when he passed out in the dessert? \nA) Hawks \nB) Verdins \nC) Vultures \nD) Eagles",
"What is the name of the Butler of the king of Pride Rock? \nA) Zen \nB) Kian \nC) Black Butler \nD) Zazu",
"What poor animal was almost eaten by Simba's uncle? \nA) Rat \nB) Bird \nC) Zazu \nD) Mouse",
"Who said \"Asante sana, Squash banana\"? \nA) Timoni \nB) Nala \nC) Rafiki \nD) Pumba" ]
```

I also put the answers in a list, like the questions:

```
var answers = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "c"]
```

Ask the user how many questions they want to play:

```
var questionsNum = Number(prompt("How many questions?"))
```

Main code, start game

```
var counter = 0;
var answersCorrect = 0;
var answersWrong = 0;
```

While loop so I can allow the user to quit:

```
while (questionsNum != counter || userAnswer != "q")  {
var userAnswer = responseChecker(quizQuestions[counter])
counter ++
answers ++
```

If statement inside while loop to alert the user if their answer is correct or wrong, and allow them to cancel by typing q, but that is not working either.

```
if (userAnswer == answers[counter]){
alert("correct")
answersCorrect ++
} else if (userAnswer != answers[counter]){
alert("wrong")
answersWrong ++
}else if (userAnswer == "q") {
 break;
}
} // end of while loop
alert("out of rounds")
```

End game mechanics

```
alert("You answered " + counter + " questions \nYou got " + questionsWrong + " questions wrong \nYou got " + questionCorrect + " questions Correct \nThank you for playing!")
```

Comment: don't use `==` to compare strings, use `equals` instead, change `userAnswer == "q"` to `userAnswer.equals("q")`,  and `userAnswer != "q"` to `!userAnswer.equals("q")`.And this part `input < "a" || input > "d" && input == "q"`.

Comment: You're not returning a value from the `responseChecker` function so `userAnswer` is always `undefined`. You should return the value of the `input` variable so you can store it in the `userAnswer1